# What are the content(elements) of posistion vector and velocity vector in the Particle Swarm Optimization (PSO) algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, particle-swarm

In the Particle Swarm Optimization (PSO) algorithm,  the position of each particle represented by a row vector ***(x)***.

The same with velocity, it represented by a velocity vector ***(v)***

I have found this in the Mathworks website:

> ...Particle i has position ***x(i)***, which is a row vector with nvars
>   elements.

What are the contents (elements) of posistion vector and velocity vector? Why they are not a single value?

Is it right if we say that ***x*** and ***v*** are **one dimension arrays** (one row and N columns)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the contents(elements) of posistion vector and velocity
>   vector?

The elements of the position are thee coordinates (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_system) which are used to parametrize space.

Similarly for the velocity vector you have the velocity in each of the dimensions.

So for instance if you have a 3D space, then the elements of position might be (x, y, z) and the elements of velocity could then be (vx, vy, vz)

> Why it is not a single value?

In general it could be an arbitrary number of values - i.e. it could be a single value. But that would mean that your swarm lives in a 1-dimensional space and hence they could also only move back and forth along that dimension.

> Is it right if we say that x and v are one dimension arrays (one row
>   and N columns)?

In principle it is. Just make sure you don't mix implementation with the abstract algorithm. Most probably the vector is represented with an array as underlying data-structure. However, if it is one row with N columns (where N would be the dimensionality of the space where your swarm lives) or if it is N rows in a single column is a matter of how one interprets it. In Mathworks, as you quoted, it says "Particle i has position x(i), which is a *row vector* with nvars elements.", so I'd say for that implementation you are correct and the right interpretation is one row with nvars columns.

Comment: what I have found is each particle position can be a candidate solution,  which will enter after that to fitness function for evaluation.  could you please tell me what is the difference between the position and the solution?

Comment: @shdotcom I have a hard time understanding what it is, what you don't understand. Basically you are looking for a point in space which satisfies some criteria (whatever your fitness function requires). The point which you find in the end is the 'solution'. Particles are at different 'positions' in space... What text are you reading? Link?

Comment: What I mean is, the solution should be a single value (number for example), and in this book. "Emerging Intelligent Computing Technology and Applications. With Aspects of Artificial Intelligence" By De-Shuang Huang. page 246, he said:
"....the position of a particle is indicated by a vector which presents a potential solution." How the position (row vector with nvars elements.) presents a potential solution (single value)?

Comment: @shdotcom: No, the solution does not need to be single value. Why would it? The algorithm is looking for a "point in space", lets call it `s`, which minimizes some fitness function `f()`. This point in space `s` is the so called solution. `s` might be a point in a 3d-space. Then it would have 3 coordinates (x, y, z). If you plug `s` into `f()` you get an output `f((x, y, z)) = out`. `out` is a single value. But that is not what we call a solution, but rather the value of the solution evaluated with the fitness function.

Comment: @shdotcom did it become any clearer or are you still confused?

Comment: thank for your help,  I really still confused, I will give you this scenario my be it will help: if I have an Array of  numbers, for example A={0.223, 0.312, 0.241, 0.342, 0.215, 0511, 0.352, 0.25, 0.143}.Each number in this array can be a potential solution. In this case how can I plug each number into f(), which as you mentioned before requires value with 3 coordinates?

Comment: @shdotcom ok, this is really strange. You are overthinking this somehow. If you have a 1d-space, then the points are a single values and so will be the solution. If you look for a point in 3d-space then you need a triple and hence the solution will be such a triplet.

Comment: @shdotcom In your example: what do this numbers mean (the array A)? Are these the particles? Or are these the coordinates of a singe particle? If you say they are 'potential solutions', then you are implicitly saying that this are particles in a 1d-space. Hence, your solution will also be a point in 1d an so the solution will be a single value. Otherwise you would have written the set of possible solutions as a set of triplets. Like so: A={(2,4,5), (8,7,2), ...}. If you mean that A is a single particle in 9-d, then also the solution will be a vector with 9 elements...

Comment: these numbers (array A) are particles (9 particles). In this case, A={(2,4,5), (8,7,2), ...}  do you mean each particle has 3 values? and if we take the first Particle will plug into f() like this f((2, 4, 5))? and if A={2, 4, 5, 3, 6}, f() will be: f(2)?

Comment: @shdotcom basically yes. If a particle has 3 or 1 coordinate depends on  the specific problem. It depends if you are looking for a point (a solution) in 3d or in 1d.... If it was 2d a point would have 2 values. A particle will have `nvars` and it depends on the dimensionality of your problem. Look at this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j028fsZZZI4 this is a 2d version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103181/discussion-between-shdotcom-and-dingalapadum).

Comment: is it posdible to convert the array A={0.223, 0.312, 0.241, 0.342, 0.215, 0511, 0.352, 0.25, 0.143} to be like this A={(0.223, 0.312, 0.241), (0.342, 0.215, 0511), (0.352, 0.25, 0.143) }, I mean each particle takes 3 numbers, and use them in the pso with 3 dimensions.

Comment: @shdotcom: of course "it is possible". What I don't know if it makes any sense. There is a fundamental difference if you are "using the algorithm" or if you are "implementing the algorithm". If you are using the algorithm, then it is _not_ your task to initialize the particles... Anyway, all this discussion is going way beyond your original question. 

I suggest you have a look at: http://ch.mathworks.com/help/gads/particleswarm.html#inputarg_fun. To _use_ the algorithm in matlab, you simply pass a function and the number of dimensions - that's it.